# How to change keyboard shortcut for switching keyboard language for any keyboard key or combination?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11, language

In windows 11
I want to **switch between keyboard languages by something else then Alt + Shift**

but also something else then the 4 options windows is suggesting

for example I want to switch languages by clicking the **F6** button

How to do it?

[image]

Comment: Use a third-party app, such as AutoHotKey or Clavier++, to interpret F6 as one of the choices.